# Чайхана или чайхона?

Tags: названия

В разных местах встречаются разные названия этих заведений. Большинство словарей, что я видел, склоняется к написанию "чайхана". Но всё же можно встретить и другое написание. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таджикском и узбекском эти слова пишутся как "чойхона" и "choyxona" соответственно, и можно ожидать, что имеется в виду местная традиция употребления чая в специальных заведениях. В Азербайджане это слово пишут через А, как и на большей части территории Средней Азии, включая Казахстан и Киргизию, и в отличие от других стран, в азербайджанских чайханах подают лишь чай со сладостями.

Начальные данные получил в этом словаре: https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0
Также вам, возможно, будет интересно ознакомиться со статьей в Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0